# Log page visits with global.asax

Tags: asp.net, logging, global-asax

I log usage on my site, by simply recording when a sessions starts and ends, and then posting it to a database, when it ends.
But now, I am interested in abit more details. To be precise, I would like to know which pages, people visit.
Can I do this in global.asax somehow? Should I make a handler instead?
What I really want to avoid, is adding logging code, on all my pages.

Comment: Can you just use the existing server logs and a statistics analyzer instead?

Comment: i'd log at the page level instead, in case you need some contextual data, otherwise use BeginRequest in global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics is the best way here.

Also, you can use Global.asax `BeginRequest` event. Here you can find the `HttpContext` and probably url of the requested bage.

Also, as an option, you can use:

- HttpModules
- Base page for all of your pages, and hadle log data on Load event for example

Comment: It's an internal site, that does not have access to google analytics.

Comment: I ended up using EndRequest. The logon identity was not available at BeginRequest, but it seemed to be at EndRequest.